# SSRS how to create dynamic title with date range

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a SSRS Report where in the Header i have inserted an expression to make the reports title dynamic, like this [report title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDME1.png)
Now i want to achieve the result that when i select invoice start date as 1st January 2018 and END Date as 1st January 2018, means one day Data i want in the title NOT to Display like ‘01 Jan 2018 and 01 Jan 2018’ means a date range, i just want '1 jan 2018' and when i select 2 different date then i want a Date range in the title.

Can anyone help me to achieve my result ?

Comment: Hi, go to your title text 'expression' and put a condition such as =IIF start date is equal to end date then title only displays start date .... May I see your expression for your dynamic title please .... Cheers

Comment: Hi Yeah sure in first expression i am just getting the value of parameter  account number which have been selected to run the report like this `=Parameters!Account_no.Value(0) ` and then i am just picking the value from invoice start date and end date selected to run the report like this `=Parameters!Invoice_Date_Start.Value` same for end date

Comment: If i understand correctly , are you looking for something like this ?
 `=IIF(Parameters!Invoice_Date_Start.Value = Parameters!Invoice_Date_End.Value), "Start and end date is the same", "Start and end date is different"` - to insert date you can use the following `=IIF(Parameters!Invoice_Date_Start.Value = Parameters!Invoice_Date_End.Value), Parameters!Invoice_Date_Start.Value,  Parameters!Invoice_Date_End.Value + " to " Parameters!Invoice_Date_End.Value` (Check the syntex please)

Comment: Hi Yes i am exactly looking for this thank you very much. got it what i want :)

Comment: no problem :) glad it helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=IIF(Parameters!Invoice_Date_Start.Value = Parameters!Invoice_Date_End.Value), "Start and end date is the same", "Start and end date is different"`

To insert the date you can use the following `=IIF(Parameters!Invoice_Date_Start.Value = Parameters!Invoice_Date_End.Value), Parameters!Invoice_Date_Start.Value, Parameters!Invoice_Date_End.Value + " to " Parameters!Invoice_Date_End.Value`

(Check the syntax please)